# Who can change ACL permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, privileges

I'm using ACL to control access to individual roots of webs for different instances of Apache and different groups of admins. I've got a Unix group `admins-web22` for admins of a particular website and user `apache-web22` for a particular instance of apache. These are the permissions set on the root directory of the web:

```
# file: web22
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:apache-web22:r-x
group::rwx
group:webmaster:rwx
group:admins-web22:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:apache-web22:r-x
default:group::rwx
default:group:admins-web22:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

There is a user `fred` which is a member of `admins-web22`. This user has full read-write access to the directory (as stated above). This works correctly. However, this user is unable to grant write permissions to user `apache-web22` for some files and directories, which is important (e.g., the web admin wants to set an upload directory for Drupal). The `setfacl` command gives "Operation not permitted.".

My question is, who can grant privileges using `setfacl`, and how can I let users of group `admins-web22` change permissions (for `apache-web22`) themselves?

I'm running Debian Wheezy and it's an ext4 partition if it's important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setfacl` manual page explains who can grant privileges:

> The file owner and processes capable of `CAP_FOWNER` are granted the right to modify ACLs of a file. This is analogous to the permissions required for accessing the file mode. (On current Linux systems, root is the only user with the `CAP_FOWNER` capability.)

So `fred` can only use `setfacl` on files he owns. Depending on your exact security requirements, you may be able to allow members of `admins-web22` to run `setfacl` as `apache-web22` (using `sudo`), which would allow them to change the ACLs on files owned by `apache-web22`....